# Additional Column in Pivot Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file like -

```
MonthYear, Rank, Department

012020, 1, HR

012020, 1, FN

022020, 1, AU

032020, 1, MK

032020, 1, HR

032020, 1, HR
```

I need the output like -

```
MonthYear, HR, FN, AU, MK

012020, 1, 1, 0, 0

022020, 0, 0, 1, 0

022020, 2, 0, 0, 1
```

I used the below command -

```
pdf = pd.pivot_table(df, values="Rank", indiex=[MonthYear], columns="Department", aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0).reset_index()

pdf.reindex(columns=['Monthyear','HR','FN','AU','MK'],fill_value=0)
pdf.to_csv('file.txt',sep=",",index=False)
```

Now issue is that if there is no row of any department in the file, then still it should show in the output file but it is not populating by even using reindex. I need all the departments('HR','FN','AU','MK') in the output file irrespective of their presence in the source file.

Any pointer please as I spent some time on google but did not get anything for String columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change `indiex=[MonthYear]` to `index='MonthYear'` for remove `[]` and `index` and also change `columns=['Monthyear','HR','FN','AU','MK']` to `columns=['MonthYear','HR','FN','AU','MK']` for correct reorder columns:

```
pdf = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                     values="Rank", 
                     index='MonthYear', 
                     columns="Department",
                     aggfunc=np.sum,
                     fill_value=0)
         .reset_index()
         .reindex(columns=['MonthYear','HR','FN','AU','MK'],fill_value=0))

print (pdf)
Department  MonthYear  HR  FN  AU  MK
0               12020   1   1   0   0
1               22020   0   0   1   0
2               32020   2   0   0   1


pdf.to_csv('file.txt',sep=",",index=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not clear.. I am able to generate the Pivot Table however I ALWAYS want HR, FN, AU, MK columns in the output whether they have rows in the source or not.

Comment: @Mohit - exactly it do my answer.

Comment: uff.. now I got the diff in your code.. I can see that you are using the reset_index and reindex same time however I was using it like below that's why it was not working. How does it make difference, can you please share?

pdf = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                     values="Rank", 
                     index='MonthYear', 
                     columns="Department",
                     aggfunc=np.sum,
                     fill_value=0)
         .reset_index())

pdf.reindex(columns=['MonthYear','HR','FN','AU','MK'],fill_value=0)

Comment: @Mohit In your code need assign back like `pdf = pdf.reindex(columns=['MonthYear','HR','FN','AU','MK'],fill_value=0) `

Comment: silly mistake from my side :( Thanks a lot jezrael for your help..

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the index, and you might want to read the first column either as a text or as datetime. if you read MonthYear as a text it looks like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['012020', 1, 'HR'],
['012020', 1, 'FN'],
['022020', 1, 'AU'],
['032020', 1, 'MK'],
['032020', 1, 'HR'],
['032020', 1, 'HR']])
df.columns = ['MonthYear', 'Rank', 'Department']
```

```
df.set_index(['MonthYear'], inplace=True)
```

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values="Rank", index='MonthYear', columns="Department", aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)
```

out put

```
Department  AU  FN  HR  MK
MonthYear               
012020  0   1   1   0
022020  1   0   0   0
032020  0   0   2   1
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not clear.. I am able to generate the Pivot Table however I ALWAYS want HR, FN, AU, MK columns in the output whether they have rows in the source or not.

Comment: I think the answer does that. see output